# How to change the value of outside variable from inside the method

Tags: python

I am trying to change the value of a variable "memes"
in a function called "joke". Joke function should change the value of memes to 1313, but it does not and when the `print(str(memes))` is triggered the value of "memes" variable is still 0.

```
class Bruhmoment:
    memes = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    global memes
    def joke(self):
        memes=1313
        print(str(memes))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a class variable (as opposed to an instance variable), you need to do things different:

```
class Bruhmoment:
    memes = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
    def joke(self):
       Bruhmoment.memes = 1313
       return Bruhmoment.memes

b = Bruhmoment('xxx')
b.joke()
=> 1313
```

Comment: Could you please tell me, will the same configuration(if one may call it so) work if I code it to return many variables or I should write individual functions for each variable?

Comment: you can return multiple values from a method, for example: `return x, y, z`. But maybe it's not a good idea? if the values are all related consider returning an instance of a new class that encapsulates them. Or if it makes sense, return a list of the values - I don't know, it depends on what you're trying to implement, and I lack the context

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the new value. Add `return memes` to the end of your function like so:

```py
def joke():
    memes = 1313
    return memes
```

Answer (score -1):

try st like this:

```
memes = 0
def joke():
    global memes
    memes = 1313
joke()
print(str(memes))
```

Comment: still no result =(

Comment: in general, we should avoid global variables